# How do I create a link to a dynamic file stored in memory from a link in html using flask and python?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

Here is a sample table that I use and all of the buttons are similar to these here. The data used for this is stored in the memory of the server and it is generated once a button is pushed.

```html
<pre>
        <table align="center" class="comic_list">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{url_for('alpha')}}"><button type="submit" value="A">A</button></a></td>
                <td><a href="{{url_for('mastercomics', _anchor= 'Action Label')}}"><button type="submit" value="Action Label">Action Label</button></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </pre>
```

Thanks
Zach

Comment: can you tell me the type of data and also where you want to display the data..in a new html or in the same ?

Comment: The data type is a csv file that desplays comics and the same html webpage

Answer (score 0):

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/alpha', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def alpha():
    master_data = pd.read_csv('path to the csv file')
    return render_template('index.html', data=master_data.to_html())

@app.route('/mastercomics/<string:anchor>')
def mastercomics(anchor):
    master_data = pd.read_csv('path to the csv file')
    return render_template('index.html', data=master_data.to_html())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <table align="center" class="comic_list">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{url_for('alpha')}}"><button type="submit" value="A">A</button></a></td>
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('mastercomics', anchor= 'Action Label') }}"><button type="submit" value="Action Label">Action Label</button></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        {% if data %}
            {{ data | safe }}
        {% endif  %}   
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!!